# update Access database from macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Dim deliveryCode As String
Set dbname = CurrentDb()
deliveryCode = 334
dbname.Execute "Update orderEntry set delivery= " & deliveryCode & " where ID=1"
```

The above code is working when deliveryCode value is an integer, but after changing deliveryCode value to a string,  I am getting error:

```
Run time error 3061 Too few parameters Expected 1
```

Comment: Try using a string: `deliveryCode = "334"`.

Comment: DeliveryCode probably needs to be literal, try adding single quotations to your SQL string: "Update orderEntry set delivery= '" & deliveryCode & "' where ID=1"